# android:lineSpacingMultiplier doesn't work in android:textAppearance

Tags: android, android-styles, android-textattributes

I'm trying to add `android:lineSpacingMultiplier` in my textAppearance style (`android:textAppearance`), and it's not working. Am I doing something wrong?

**TextAppearance style:**

```
<style name="TextAppearance.Body1" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1">
      <item name="android:lineSpacingMultiplier">1.25</item>
</style>
```

**Use of style:**

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="This is body 1\nThis is body 1"
    android:textAppearance="TextAppearance.Body1"
    />
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For whatever reason `android:lineSpacingMultiplier` doesn't work as an item within your `textAppearance`. You'll either have to set it directly as a `TextView` attribute (using `android:lineSpacingMultiplier`), or create a regular style which "wraps" setting the `textAppearance` and `lineSpacingMultiplier`

Create a style

```
<style name="TextBody1">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1</item>
    <item name="android:lineSpacingMultiplier">1.25</item>
</style>
```

or

```
<style name="TextBody1" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1">
    <item name="android:lineSpacingMultiplier">1.25</item>
</style>
```

and then apply via `style` instead of `android:textAppearance`

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="This is body 1\nThis is body 1"
    style="@style/TextBody1"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

`lineSpacingMultiplier` as well as `lineSpacingExtra` you can apply only in style.

But as an alternative, you can use `lineHeight` attribute, which can be applied to the `MaterialTextView` using `textAppearance`.

Interesting note, that if you use a fully Material theme (not Bridge) all your `TextView` will auto-inflate to `MaterialTextView`, otherwise, you will need to specify `<com.google.android.material.textview` in your xml.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by simply applying the `style` to the `TextView` itself instead of the `textAppearance` (similar to the accepted answer, but with a bit less code).

Here is a sample:

Style:

```
<style name="TextBody1" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1">
  <item name="android:lineSpacingMultiplier">1.25</item>
</style>
```

or simpler if you don't care about the parent:

```
<style name="TextBody1">
      <item name="android:lineSpacingMultiplier">1.25</item>
</style>
```

Then in your View:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="This is body 1\nThis is body 1"
    style="@style/TextBody1"
    />
```

I am not sure why applying `android:textAppearance` to a `TextView` with a given `style` that defines `android:lineSpacingMultiplier` does not work (I would speculate that it may be due to the fact that the line spacing is on the style `View` itself instead of the `textAppearance` of the `View`) but this is a bit simpler than the accepted answer if you don't care about the parent.